# Qt Creator + GDB + MingW - Bitwise And question

Tags: c, qt, gdb, mingw

I tried to evaluate how bitwise AND operation results get evaluated. I am using Qt Creator + GDB + MingW on Windows.

I did an simple test:

```
#define BITMASK_CAN_JUMP 1 << 0 // 0x0001
#define BITMASK_CAN_WALK 1 << 1 // 0x0010

unsigned int data = BITMASK_CAN_JUMP | BITMASK_CAN_WALK;
...
    if (data & BITMASK_CAN_WALK) {
        printf("%d", data & BITMASK_CAN_WALK);
        printf("can walk\n");
    }
...
```

Setting an watch in GDB for (data & 0x0010) gives me the value 0 because 0x0010 = 0b10000 which is correct. The if condition evaluates to true because the value gets evaluated as 2. To me it seems like the the debugger acts correctly by treating 0x0010 as an hexadecimal value while the program itself gets some kind of implicit conversion, like converting the value behind data to an hexadecimal value. I don't understand why data doesn't get converted to hexadecimal then, too, when using GDB.
Could somebody clear up the situation to me?

Best
Tom

Comment: Using 0b0010 works correctly in GDB.

Comment: `BITMASK_CAN_WALK 1 << 1` is not `0x0010` like that comment would suggest, it's `0x0002`, or `0b0010`.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that. The bitmask somehow gets displayed as 0x0010 in GDB.

Comment: Thats why I asked myself why the define seems to evaluate to 0x0010 and what kind of invisible conversion takes part when running the code. To me it seems like data & 0x0010 (which is the value I got from the IDE for the define) behavious different in GDB than the actual program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the correct values of the defines:

```
#define BITMASK_CAN_JUMP 1 << 0 // 0b0001
#define BITMASK_CAN_WALK 1 << 1 // 0b0010
```

You might at least want to put braces around the `1 << 0` and `1 << 1`, but that's another story. Anyway, `data` becomes `0b10 | 0b01`, which is `0b11`, or `3` in decimal.

`(data & BITMASK_CAN_WALK)` is `0b11 & 0b10`, which is `0b10`, or `2` in decimal.

Therefore, the `if (data & BITMASK_CAN_WALK)` is taken, because it is not `0` (in C++ it would be implicitly casted to `true`), and it prints the aforementioned `2`. If you change the format specifier to `#010x` you'll see that it indeed is `0x2`.

Nothing here has the value `0x0010` (`16` in decimal), maybe there's a display bug if you're seeing that value.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought and how I understood it. Could be an display issue with preprocessed defines. Creating const unsigned ints with the same bitmask displays me the correct value in GDB.